# Rails 3 Devise Update Password Without Logging Out

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, passwords, devise

I'm Using Devise in my Rails 3.0.9 application for User Authentication. As I wanted to be able to manage Users, I created the following Users Controllers:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  
  def index
     @users = User.all
   end

   def new
     @user = User.new
   end

   def create
     @user = User.new(params[:user])
     if @user.save
       flash[:notice] = "Successfully created User." 
       redirect_to users_path
     else
       render :action => 'new'
     end
   end

   def edit
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
   end

   def update
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
     params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:user][:password].blank? and params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
     if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
       if current_user.update_with_password(params[:user])
           sign_in(current_user, :bypass => true)
       end
       flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated User."
       redirect_to users_path
     else
       render :action => 'edit'
     end
   end

   def destroy
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     if @user.destroy
       flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted User."
       redirect_to users_path
     end
   end
  
end
```

I this works for showing, creating and deleting Users, but I have run into a problem when updating the passwords.

When I Update the password for the currently logged in account it automatically logs me out.

In the controller I tried to fix this using: (you can see it in the code above)

```
if current_user.update_with_password(params[:user])
   sign_in(current_user, :bypass => true)
end
```

But that gives me this error ->

```
undefined method `update_with_password' for nil:NilClass
```

What I'm really looking for, is the ability to update any accounts password, without logging them out ( as admins have ability to change regular users password ).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not necessary to write

This code in the controller

```
if current_user.update_with_password(params[:user])
  sign_in(current_user, :bypass => true)
end
```

Instead you should go ahead with below one

```
if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
   sign_in(current_user, :bypass => true)
   redirect_to users_path
end
```

cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is call

```
sign_in(current_user, :bypass => true)
```

After the update.

This is what my controller action looks like:

```
def update_password
  if current_user.update_with_password(params[:user])
    sign_in(current_user, bypass: true)
    flash[:notice] = "Updated Password Successfully"
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error updating your password, please try again."
  end
end
```

I think this is basically what @challenge proposed but I just wanted to make a little cleaner and easier to understand.